# Filters vs CSS Sprites - CSS3 fallback

Tags: performance, css

I have a problem, i am creating a button element which contains a lot of effects e.g. border radius, box shadow, inner shadow, text shadow, gradient etc.

I want to create this element with CSS3, but i am required to support both IE7/8.

Do you recommend filters or sprites as a fallback?

If you provide a answer, could you also explain which renders quicker as well as which is more bulletproof?

Many thanks in advance,

B

Answer (score 2):

I use filters for linear gradients and opacity. I find they load quicker than the overhead of a http request and render associated with downloading a sprite.

Although if that sprite is cached you'd probably find this is more performant on a larger site.

I use [CSS3please](http://css3please.com) for reference.

Comment: @beartwizzle is wise. i must ask, how many images are you going to need for ie7/8? if it's a small number, the sprite wouldn't be that big....but using/learning filters is awesome for growth

Comment: I've noticed border radius is not available in filter format .... do you have any suggestions for a fallback? .... I want to be as performant as possible

Comment: You could use CSS3Pie http://www.css3pie.com (its quite large, but you could conditionally load it for older IE browsers only)

Comment: @beartwizzle - I did use css3pie but i had numerous problems with z-index issues as well as people on slower connections were seeing the elements which had the behaivour applied jump up and down the screen ..... i think this was caused by the element being absolutly positioned to sit behind the target element. i could not take this risk as the site which it was applied on was getting millions of hits per day

Comment: @Ben - Yes I had similar experiences with absolute positioned elements. In the end I decided to go down the route of saying users of older browsers don't get an 'as polished' experience.